# Imacros. How to save several images with changing attributes?

Tags: javascript, image, save, imacros

I need to save 4 images everytime i refresh a website, the problem is, it only has 1 attribute that is different in all these images and it changes into a randomly generated string everytime i refresh the page. the HTML of these images are:

```
<img alt="" width="35" height="40" src="data:image/png;base64,HJFFSYYEYGUG3r236=">
<img alt="" width="35" height="40" src="data:image/png;base64,UASFsACUYASYGU6=">
<img alt="" width="35" height="40" src="data:image/png;base64,FHJASFUYYetetgts=">
<img alt="" width="35" height="40" src="data:image/png;base64,ete6tdrte6r=">
```

so as you can see the only the src attribute changes. How do i save all 4 of these images every time i refresh the page?

Answer (score 1):

Replace the changeable part of SRC-attribute with the wildcard * and run the macro in loop mode (with the max. loop number = 4):

```
TAG POS={{!LOOP}} TYPE=IMG ATTR=SRC:"data:image/png;base64,*=" CONTENT=EVENT:SAVEITEM
```

If it doesn’t work, try the event:

```
... CONTENT=EVENT:SAVE_ELEMENT_SCREENSHOT
```

Comment: or you can try with CONTENT=EVENT:SAVEPICTUREAS